# How to piecewise uncover a single graphic on a beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, includegraphics, transition, uncover, only

I'd like to have a beamer frame wherein a single large figure typeset centrally is typeset at `0.8\textwidth`. The difficulty is that I need to uncover this piecewise in place i.e. the top 30% in slide 1, another next 60% in slide 2, and finally the bottom 10% in slide 3 (revealing the full figure).

Note that using `\only`, `\uncover` etc in conjunction with  `trim`/`clip` options to `\includegraphics` causes a re-centering of the trimmed portion, leading to a "wobbling" effect. I just need the figure to be anchored/fixed, and the different horizontal sections unvieled slide-by-slide.

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my large figure}

\centering
\includegraphics{some_figure.pdf}  % ---> a suitable vector graphics pdf image can be substituted here
% How do I have 3 slides wherein the single large figure remains anchored in place while doing a piecewise reveal to the top 30%, additional 60%, and the bottom 10%?

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place your figure in a named node within a `tikzpicture`, you can then cover parts of the figure using white rectangles and coordinates of the named figure node. In the example below, the rectangles are drawn in red for illustration, but `draw=red` would normally be omitted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my large figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node<1-4>[inner sep=0](mypic){\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[shape=coordinate](p1) at ($(mypic.north west)!0.3!(mypic.south west)$){};
\node[shape=coordinate](p2) at ($(mypic.north west)!0.9!(mypic.south west)$){};
\only<1>{\fill[white,draw=red] (p1) rectangle (mypic.north east);}
\only<1-2>{\fill[white,draw=red] (p2) rectangle (p1 -| mypic.north east);}
\only<1-3>{\fill[white,draw=red] (p2) rectangle (mypic.south east);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]